# Why is open mapping a geometric property?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

I was recently reading Chapter 3 on meromorphic functions in "Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi". They mentioned that the property that holomorphic functions are open mappings is a geometric property. My question is that why openness is a geometric property? I know openness, closeness, compactness, and connectedness are concepts in topology, but I still can't understand intuitively why the openness and closeness of a map is geometric property.

Comment: One reason is that non constant holomorphic functions are conformal (preserve angles) except at a discrete set of points where the derivative is zero and there they multiply angles by a positive integer $n+1$ where $n$ is the order of the zero of the derivative, so they preserve infinitesimal discs possibly going through them $n+1$ times; in short the local degree of a non constant holomorphic map is a non zero (positive) integer and that implies openess (this of course is a topological property but could be proven using angles hence geometrically)

Comment: @Conrad This is correct, but I do not see why openness is a geometric property. In multivariable real calculus there are open smooth maps on $\mathbb R^2$ which are not conformal.

Comment: Many mathematicians consider (at least real/complex point-set) topology a subfield of geometry. If this is the case, openness is a topological, hence geometric property.

Comment: @Paul not disagreeing, just mentioned a reason why the authors of the treatise may have claimed that - topologically the most significant property of non constant holomorphic functions is the local positive degree - there are harmonic complex functions that have isolated values but still have local degree zero at the origin say and which are not open as they miss a ray on any small open disc centered at zero (this is actually how one proves the degree is zero)